# How can I add additional required fields to Django's "User Add" administration page?

Tags: django, django-admin

When adding a new user to my Django application, I'd like to ensure that the administration page requires an administrator to include the "email" field.

I've tried tinkering with the UserAdminForm object, but I've come up empty thus far.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add something like this to one of your project's admin.py files:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User


# Override username field require email address
class UserCreationForm2(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75, required=True)

class UserChangeForm2(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75, required=True)

class UserAdmin2(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm2
    add_form = UserCreationForm2

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin2)
```

Essentially, make the email field required, unregister the built-in admin, and register a new admin with the override.